# Additional content won't sit below wrapped DIVs positioned to stack for mobile devices

Tags: html, css

I have two sections for use cases and benefits on a site. As follows.

```css
.onboardmessaging {
    min-width: 100%;  
}

.onboardmessagingwrap {
    min-width: 100%;  
}

.usecase {
    padding-left: 8vw;
    max-width: 50%;
    float: left;
}

.benefits {
    padding-right: 8vw;
    max-width: 50%;
    float: right;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
.usecase {
    padding-left: 0;
    min-width: 100%;
    float: left;
}
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
.benefits {
    padding-right: 0;
    min-width: 100%;
    float: right;
}
}
```

```html
<div class="onboardmessagingwrap">
  <div class="onboardmessaging">
    <div class="usecase">
       <p class="title">Title</p>
       <p class="sentence">1</p>
       <p class="sentence">2</p>
       <p class="sentence">3</p>
       <p class="sentence">4</p>
    </div>
    <div class="benefits">
       <p class="title">Title</p>
       <p class="sentence">1</p>
       <p class="sentence">2</p>
       <p class="sentence">3</p>
       <p class="sentence">4</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<p>Why does this sit underneath and not below the lists?</p>
```

They sit fine next to each other but any more content that gets added to the page ends up sitting below it, rather than next to it. I'm really not sure why this is as I've closed all of the DIVs and added an extra one.

The message `Why does this sit underneath and not below the lists?` should be below it.

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: because you are floating: add `overflow: hidden` to `onboardmessagingwrap` element

Comment: maybe you can use `flex-box` instead of `float`. check this out https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 0):

You want to clear the float. This is a common way to do so.

Replace the

```
    <br>
```

with

```
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
```

and add to your CSS

```
    .clearfix::after {
      content: "";
      clear: both;
      display: table;
    }
```

Alternatively, you can also add the clearfix class to the onboardmessagingwrap div and achieve the same result without adding an erroneous div.

For more info on CSS floats see: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp